# Publishing fails in Cloud Search with error Could not load SearchIndexer

Tags: publishing, web8.5, si4t, publishingfailed

We have migrated SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 to Web 8.5 and while configuring AWS cloud search by taking jars from SDL.DXA.Search.Module.2.0\modules\Search\deployer\lib\si4t-cloudsearch

After that when published it failed with below error

> Could not load SearchIndexer. Check your configuration.

Stack trace

```
2018-12-21 07:41:23,243 ERROR TridionCommitStep - Commit failed for execution id:tcm:0-2419420-66560
com.sdl.delivery.deployer.api.processing.exception.ProcessingException: Unable to commit transactions. ExecutionId:tcm:0-2419420-66560
    at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.steps.TridionTransactionalExecutableStep.commitTransaction(TridionTransactionalExecutableStep.java:78)
    at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.steps.TridionCommitStep.process(TridionCommitStep.java:28)
    at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.engine.pipeline.actor.StepActor.execute(StepActor.scala:72)
    at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.engine.pipeline.actor.StepActor.com$sdl$delivery$deployer$engine$pipeline$actor$StepActor$$processStep(StepActor.scala:57)
    at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.engine.pipeline.actor.StepActor$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(StepActor.scala:40)
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:480)
    at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.engine.pipeline.actor.StepActor.aroundReceive(StepActor.scala:26)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:526)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:495)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:257)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:224)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.tridion.broker.StorageException: Commit failed for transaction tcm:0-2419420-66560 because of com.tridion.storage.si4t.IndexingException: Could not load SearchIndexer. Check your configuration.
    at com.tridion.storage.management.TransactionManagerImpl.commitTransaction(TransactionManagerImpl.java:70)
    at com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.commitTransaction(StorageManagerFactory.java:226)
    at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.steps.TridionTransactionalExecutableStep.commitTransaction(TridionTransactionalExecutableStep.java:76)
    ... 13 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.tridion.broker.StorageException: com.tridion.storage.si4t.IndexingException: Could not load SearchIndexer. Check your configuration.
    at com.tridion.storage.si4t.JPASearchDAOFactory.commitTransaction(JPASearchDAOFactory.java:202)
    at com.tridion.storage.management.TransactionManagerImpl.commitTransaction(TransactionManagerImpl.java:65)
    ... 15 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.tridion.storage.si4t.IndexingException: Could not load SearchIndexer. Check your configuration.
    at com.tridion.storage.si4t.SearchIndexProcessor.triggerIndexing(SearchIndexProcessor.java:262)
    at com.tridion.storage.si4t.JPASearchDAOFactory.commitTransaction(JPASearchDAOFactory.java:189)
    ... 16 common frames omitted
```

I am using only single deployer service and configured storage node for publications which uses AWS Cloud Search Module and Other Storage for remaining publications as shown below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Configuration xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Version="8.5" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="schemas/cd_storage_conf.xsd">
    <Namespace default="tcm"/>
    <Global>
        <ObjectCache Enabled="false">
            <Policy Class="com.tridion.cache.LRUPolicy" Type="LRU">
                <Param Name="MemSize" Value="16mb"/>
            </Policy>
            <Features>
                <Feature Class="com.tridion.cache.DependencyTracker" Type="DependencyTracker"/>
            </Features>
        </ObjectCache>
        <Storages>
            <StorageBindings>
                <Bundle src="SearchDAOBundle.xml"/>
            </StorageBindings>
            <Storage Class="com.tridion.storage.si4t.JPASearchDAOFactory" Id="sqlServer" Type="persistence" dialect="MSSQL">
                <Pool CheckoutTimeout="120" IdleTimeout="120" MonitorInterval="60" Size="5" Type="jdbc"/>
                <DataSource Class="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource">
                    <Property Name="serverName" Value="DEVAG02\SQL01"/>
                    <Property Name="portNumber" Value="9561"/>
                    <Property Name="databaseName" Value="Tridion"/>
                    <Property Name="user" Value="TridionBroker"/>
                    <Property Name="password" Value="Tridion"/>
                </DataSource>
                <Indexer Class="org.si4t.cloudsearch.CloudSearchIndexer" DocExtensions="pdf,docx,doc,xls,xlsx,pptx,ppt,xml,jpg,png" access_key_id="KEW6HC74334" authentication="explicit" documentEndpoint="doc-dev-live-le-5yist4ubp3pr2gq3pbwevm22uq.eu-west-1.cloudsearch.amazonaws.com" indexBatchSize="20" secret_access_key="QT5LDTKcg2tyVq9TP70k7fOqM9/pS"/>
            </Storage>
            <Storage Class="com.tridion.storage.persistence.JPADAOFactory" Id="defaultdb" Type="persistence" dialect="MSSQL">
                <Pool CheckoutTimeout="120" IdleTimeout="120" MonitorInterval="60" Size="5" Type="jdbc"/>
                <DataSource Class="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource">
                    <Property Name="serverName" Value="DEVAG02\SQL01"/>
                    <Property Name="portNumber" Value="9561"/>
                    <Property Name="databaseName" Value="Tridion_Broker"/>
                    <Property Name="user" Value="Tridion"/>
                    <Property Name="password" Value="Tridion"/>
                </DataSource>
            </Storage>
            <Storage Class="com.tridion.storage.filesystem.FSDAOFactory" Id="defaultFile" Type="filesystem" defaultFilesystem="false">
                <Root Path="D:\DevLivePublic\live"/>
            </Storage>
            <Storage Class="com.tridion.storage.filesystem.FSDAOFactory" Id="cie_index_files" Type="filesystem" defaultFilesystem="false" defaultStorage="false">
                <Root Path="D:\DevLivePublic\live\CIE\SearchIndex\Resources"/>
            </Storage>
            <Storage Class="com.tridion.storage.filesystem.FSDAOFactory" Id="ocr_index_files" Type="filesystem" defaultFilesystem="false" defaultStorage="false">
                <Root Path="D:\DevLivePublic\live\OC\SearchIndex\Resources"/>
            </Storage>
            <Storage Class="com.tridion.storage.filesystem.FSDAOFactory" Id="ce_index_files" Type="filesystem" defaultFilesystem="false" defaultStorage="false">
                <Root Path="D:\DevLivePublic\live\ESOL\SearchIndex\Resources"/>
                <Indexer Class="org.si4t.cloudsearch.CloudSearchIndexer" DocExtensions="pdf,docx,doc,xls,xlsx,pptx,ppt,xml,jpg,png" access_key_id="AKIKEW6HC74" authentication="explicit" documentEndpoint="doc-dev-live-le-5yist4ubp3pr2gwevm22uq.eu-west-1.cloudsearch.amazonaws.com" indexBatchSize="20" secret_access_key="QT54AZNTLDTKcg2tyVq9TP70k7fOqM9/pS"/>
            </Storage>
        </Storages>
        <Transaction MonitorInterval="5000" Timeout="10000000"/>
    </Global>
    <ItemTypes cached="false" defaultStorageId="defaultdb">
        <Item cached="true" storageId="defaultFile" typeMapping="Page"/>
        <Item cached="true" storageId="defaultFile" typeMapping="Binary"/>
        <Publication Id="31" cached="true" defaultStorageId="defaultdb">
            <Item cached="true" storageId="defaultFile" typeMapping="Page"/>
            <Item cached="true" storageId="defaultFile" typeMapping="Binary"/>
            <Item cached="false" itemExtension=".xml" storageId="cie_index_files" typeMapping="ComponentPresentation"/>
        </Publication>
        <Publication Id="33" cached="true" defaultStorageId="defaultdb">
            <Item cached="true" storageId="defaultFile" typeMapping="Page"/>
            <Item cached="true" storageId="defaultFile" typeMapping="Binary"/>
            <Item cached="false" itemExtension=".xml" storageId="ocr_index_files" typeMapping="ComponentPresentation"/>
        </Publication>
        <Publication Id="32" cached="true" defaultStorageId="sqlServer">
            <Item cached="true" storageId="defaultFile" typeMapping="Page"/>
            <Item cached="true" storageId="defaultFile" typeMapping="Binary"/>
            <Item cached="false" itemExtension=".htm" storageId="sqlServer" typeMapping="Page"/>
            <Item cached="false" itemExtension=".xml" storageId="ce_index_files" typeMapping="ComponentPresentation"/>
        </Publication>
        <Publication Id="141" cached="true" defaultStorageId="defaultdb"/>
        <Publication Id="142" cached="true" defaultStorageId="defaultdb"/>
        <Publication Id="123" cached="true" defaultStorageId="defaultdb"/>
    </ItemTypes>
    <ConfigRepository CacheEnabled="true" CacheExpirationDuration="600" ClientId="registration" ClientSecret="encrypted:HzfQh9wYwAKShDxCm4DnnBnysAz9PtbDMFXMbPszSVY=" ConnectionTimeout="20000" ServiceMonitorPollDuration="10" ServiceUri="http://cdlive-dev:9082/discovery.svc" TokenServiceUrl="http://cdlive-dev:9082/token.svc">
        <Roles>
            <Role Name="DeployerCapability" Url="http://cdlive-dev:9084/httpupload">
                <Property Name="encoding" Value="UTF-8"/>
            </Role>
        </Roles>
    </ConfigRepository>
</Configuration>
```

Search DAO bundle

```
    <StorageDAOBundle type="filesystem">
        <StorageDAO typeMapping="Page" class="com.tridion.storage.si4t.dao.FSSearchPageDAO"/>
        <StorageDAO typeMapping="Binary" class="com.tridion.storage.si4t.dao.FSSearchBinaryContentDAO"/>
        <StorageDAO typeMapping="ComponentPresentation" class="com.tridion.storage.si4t.dao.FSSearchComponentPresentationDAO"/>
    </StorageDAOBundle>
<StorageDAOBundle type="persistence">
            <StorageDAO typeMapping="Page" class="com.tridion.storage.si4t.dao.JPASearchPageDAO"/>
            <StorageDAO typeMapping="Binary" class="com.tridion.storage.si4t.dao.JPASearchBinaryContentDAO"/>
            <StorageDAO typeMapping="ComponentPresentation" class="com.tridion.storage.si4t.dao.JPASearchComponentPresentationDAO"/>
        </StorageDAOBundle>
```

Deployed JAR files

```
aspectjrt.jar                                                                                 
aspectjweaver.jar                                                                             
aws-java-sdk-1.9.6.jar                                                                        
aws-java-sdk-autoscaling-1.9.6.jar                                                            
aws-java-sdk-cloudformation-1.9.6.jar                                                         
aws-java-sdk-cloudfront-1.9.6.jar                                                             
aws-java-sdk-cloudsearch-1.9.6.jar                                                            
aws-java-sdk-cloudtrail-1.9.6.jar                                                             
aws-java-sdk-cloudwatch-1.9.6.jar                                                             
aws-java-sdk-cloudwatchmetrics-1.9.6.jar                                                      
aws-java-sdk-codedeploy-1.9.6.jar                                                             
aws-java-sdk-cognitoidentity-1.9.6.jar                                                        
aws-java-sdk-cognitosync-1.9.6.jar                                                            
aws-java-sdk-config-1.9.6.jar                                                                 
aws-java-sdk-core-1.9.6.jar                                                                   
aws-java-sdk-datapipeline-1.9.6.jar                                                           
aws-java-sdk-directconnect-1.9.6.jar                                                          
aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.9.6.jar                                                               
aws-java-sdk-ec2-1.9.6.jar                                                                    
aws-java-sdk-elasticache-1.9.6.jar                                                            
aws-java-sdk-elasticbeanstalk-1.9.6.jar                                                       
aws-java-sdk-elasticloadbalancing-1.9.6.jar                                                   
aws-java-sdk-elastictranscoder-1.9.6.jar                                                      
aws-java-sdk-emr-1.9.6.jar                                                                    
aws-java-sdk-glacier-1.9.6.jar                                                                
aws-java-sdk-iam-1.9.6.jar                                                                    
aws-java-sdk-importexport-1.9.6.jar                                                           
aws-java-sdk-kinesis-1.9.6.jar                                                                
aws-java-sdk-kms-1.9.6.jar                                                                    
aws-java-sdk-lambda-1.9.6.jar                                                                 
aws-java-sdk-logs-1.9.6.jar                                                                   
aws-java-sdk-opsworks-1.9.6.jar                                                               
aws-java-sdk-rds-1.9.6.jar                                                                    
aws-java-sdk-redshift-1.9.6.jar                                                               
aws-java-sdk-route53-1.9.6.jar                                                                
aws-java-sdk-s3-1.9.6.jar                                                                     
aws-java-sdk-ses-1.9.6.jar                                                                    
aws-java-sdk-simpledb-1.9.6.jar                                                               
aws-java-sdk-simpleworkflow-1.9.6.jar                                                         
aws-java-sdk-sns-1.9.6.jar                                                                    
aws-java-sdk-sqs-1.9.6.jar                                                                    
aws-java-sdk-storagegateway-1.9.6.jar                                                         
aws-java-sdk-sts-1.9.6.jar                                                                    
aws-java-sdk-support-1.9.6.jar                                                                
aws-java-sdk-swf-libraries-1.9.6.jar                                                          
commons-codec-1.6.jar                                                                         
commons-logging-1.1.3.jar                                                                     
gson-2.2.2.jar                                                                                
httpclient-4.3.6.jar                                                                          
httpcore-4.3.3.jar                                                                            
jackson-annotations-2.5.0.jar                                                                 
jackson-core-2.5.3.jar                                                                        
jackson-databind-2.5.3.jar                                                                    
javax.mail-api-1.4.6.jar                                                                      
joda-time-2.8.1.jar                                                                           
si4t-1.0.jar                                                                                  
si4t-cloudsearch-1.0.jar
```

Apart from AWS cloud Search I need to configure Solr search also in same deployer, can I do that?

Can you please suggest me where i am doing mistake.

Additional Information:

New error log

```
2018-12-23 05:37:14,724 DEBUG StorageManagerImpl - Loading a non cached DAO for publicationId/typeMapping/itemExtension: 32 / Binary / .png
2018-12-23 05:37:14,724 ERROR ReflectionUtil - The constructor of the target class has thrown an exception
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor164.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.tridion.util.ReflectionUtil.loadClassInstanceWithTypes(ReflectionUtil.java:63)
    at com.tridion.storage.filesystem.FSDAOFactory.getDAOForTypeMappingInTransaction(FSDAOFactory.java:106)
    at com.tridion.storage.management.StorageManagerImpl.getOriginalDAO(StorageManagerImpl.java:179)
    at com.tridion.storage.management.StorageManagerImpl.getDAO(StorageManagerImpl.java:151)
    at com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.getDAO(StorageManagerFactory.java:175)
    at com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.getDAOForTransaction(StorageManagerFactory.java:133)
    at com.tridion.storage.deploy.workers.BinaryWorker.doDeploy(BinaryWorker.java:97)
    at com.tridion.deployer.model.transaction.TransactionLogItemWorker.doWork(TransactionLogItemWorker.java:42)
    at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.steps.TridionPreCommitStep.process(TridionPreCommitStep.java:69)
    at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.engine.pipeline.actor.StepActor.execute(StepActor.scala:72)
    at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.engine.pipeline.actor.StepActor.com$sdl$delivery$deployer$engine$pipeline$actor$StepActor$$processStep(StepActor.scala:57)
    at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.engine.pipeline.actor.StepActor$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(StepActor.scala:40)
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:480)
    at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.engine.pipeline.actor.StepActor.aroundReceive(StepActor.scala:26)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:526)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:495)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:257)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:224)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.tridion.configuration.ConfigurationException: Indexable file extensions are not configured.
    at com.tridion.storage.si4t.dao.FSSearchBinaryContentDAO.setIndexableFileExtensions(FSSearchBinaryContentDAO.java:86)
    at com.tridion.storage.si4t.dao.FSSearchBinaryContentDAO.<init>(FSSearchBinaryContentDAO.java:57)
    ... 24 common frames omitted
2018-12-23 05:37:14,724 WARN  TridionTransactionalExecutableStep - Rollback transaction due to error. ExecutionId: tcm:0-2419616-66560 error: Unable to load the file system based binding within a transaction.
```

Error log after updating cd storage config

```
2018-12-23 15:59:00,374 DEBUG JDBCDataSourceBeanConfigurer - Registering JDBC data source
2018-12-23 15:59:00,374 DEBUG PooledDataSourceBeanConfigurer - Initializing Pooled data source
2018-12-23 15:59:00,374 DEBUG EntityManagerFactoryBeanConfigurer - Registering EntityManagerFactory to Spring Context
2018-12-23 15:59:00,436 DEBUG LocalThreadTransaction - Received a set on the new method with value: null
2018-12-23 15:59:00,436 WARN  StepActor - Step 'PageDeploy' for 'tcm:0-2419617-66560' failed with message: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'storageFactoryConfigurationLoader': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.tridion.configuration.ConfigurationException: Could not load DAO Factory class: com.tridion.storage.si4t.JPADAOFactory
2018-12-23 15:59:00,452 DEBUG HybridStateStore - Found step entity for execution id: tcm:0-2419617-66560, pipeline id: Tridion-Process-Deploy and step id: PageDeploy
2018-12-23 15:59:00,467 ERROR StepActor - Step 'PageDeploy' for 'tcm:0-2419617-66560' can NOT retry
2018-12-23 15:59:00,467 ERROR StepActor - Step 'PageDeploy' for 'tcm:0-2419617-66560': 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'storageFactoryConfigurationLoader': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.tridion.configuration.ConfigurationException: Could not load DAO Factory class: com.tridion.storage.si4t.JPADAOFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:408)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1575)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:751)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.tridion.cd.core.kernel.SpringContentDeliveryKernel.ensureInitialised(SpringContentDeliveryKernel.java:38)
    at com.tridion.cd.core.kernel.KernelFactory.registerKernel(KernelFactory.java:40)
    at com.tridion.cd.core.kernel.KernelFactory.getKernel(KernelFactory.java:27)
    at com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.getComponent(StorageManagerFactory.java:70)
    at com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.getStorageManager(StorageManagerFactory.java:49)
    at com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.getDAO(StorageManagerFactory.java:175)
    at com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.getDAO(StorageManagerFactory.java:121)
    at com.tridion.storage.deploy.PageHandler.deploy(PageHandler.java:64)
    at com.tridion.deployer.DeploymentHandler.deploy(DeploymentHandler.java:101)
    at com.tridion.deployer.modules.PageDeploy.processPage(PageDeploy.java:151)
    at com.tridion.deployer.modules.PageDeploy.processItem(PageDeploy.java:118)
    at com.tridion.deployer.SectionVisitor.processSection(SectionVisitor.java:74)
    at com.tridion.deployer.SectionVisitor.processSection(SectionVisitor.java:78)
    at com.tridion.deployer.SectionVisitor.processSection(SectionVisitor.java:78)
    at com.tridion.deployer.SectionVisitor.processSection(SectionVisitor.java:78)
    at com.tridion.deployer.SectionVisitor.process(SectionVisitor.java:51)
    at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.steps.TridionDeployerStepAdapter.process(TridionDeployerStepAdapter.java:91)
    at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.engine.pipeline.actor.StepActor.execute(StepActor.scala:72)
    at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.engine.pipeline.actor.StepActor.com$sdl$delivery$deployer$engine$pipeline$actor$StepActor$$processStep(StepActor.scala:57)
    at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.engine.pipeline.actor.StepActor$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(StepActor.scala:40)
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:480)
    at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.engine.pipeline.actor.StepActor.aroundReceive(StepActor.scala:26)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:526)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:495)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:257)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:224)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.tridion.configuration.ConfigurationException: Could not load DAO Factory class: com.tridion.storage.si4t.JPADAOFactory
    at com.tridion.storage.configuration.StorageFactoryConfigurationLoader.configureStorage(StorageFactoryConfigurationLoader.java:132)
    at com.tridion.storage.configuration.StorageFactoryConfigurationLoader.configure(StorageFactoryConfigurationLoader.java:73)
    at com.tridion.storage.configuration.StorageFactoryConfigurationLoader.initialize(StorageFactoryConfigurationLoader.java:53)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:365)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:310)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:133)
    ... 42 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.tridion.storage.si4t.JPADAOFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.sdl.delivery.service.ParentLastClassLoader.loadClass(ParentLastClassLoader.java:45)
    at com.sdl.delivery.service.ParentLastClassLoader.loadClass(ParentLastClassLoader.java:31)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at com.tridion.storage.configuration.StorageFactoryConfigurationLoader.configureStorage(StorageFactoryConfigurationLoader.java:123)
    ... 51 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Please provide the full ERROR trace logs?, also update your question and provide the ItemTypes mapping of your cd_storage config?

Comment: Thank you Velmurugan, for quick response, I updated my question.

Comment: Also, update your cd_storage config ItemTypes section config too, since you have used multiple storage ids, want to see your publication id mapping in the ItemTypes

Comment: Updated item types section

Comment: I can see there is  no mapping for your Id sqlServer Storage, and defaultdb there is no mapping for SI4T Indexer, so clearly it's an issue with your cd_strorage_config ItemTypes mapping

Comment: Thank you Velmurugan, after updating item types the above error resolved, but still as i given in additional logs committing deployment phase failing, i have updated Item types for publication id 32 and shared storage dao xml, I try to update extensions but still issue not resolved.

Comment: In the Indexer DocExtensions binary index feature is not done for AWS cloud search, it won’t work so make sure to keep the extension which is not exist in Tridion eg DocExtensions=“txt”

Comment: I think you are implementing si4t search the first time, not migrating from 2013sp1 + solr to Web 8.5 + AWS cloudsearch, also noticed that **defaultFile** there is no storage mapping, your ItemTypes misconfigured, I'm not sure about your Items which types are going to store in FS and DB

Comment: we are storing .htm files in DB and rest of the files in FS including component presentations for indexing storing also in FS, we want component presenations to be indexed, thats why i configured .xml and after looking error i added .jpg and .png for testing. Long back some team implemented search, since we dont have sufficient documentation , implementing as new.

Comment: Please edit and update your full cd_storage_config file, mask your credentials stuffs in the config? still config I have not seen your Id **defaultFile** <Storage Class="com.tridion.storage.filesystem.FSDAOFactory" Id="defaultFile" Type="filesystem" defaultFilesystem="false">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your cd_storage_config is not configured correctly as expected, noticed that si4t class is not called in your storage mapping for your filesystem.

Try this below-updated cd_storage_config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Configuration xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Version="8.5" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="schemas/cd_storage_conf.xsd">
<Namespace default="tcm"/>
<Global>
    <ObjectCache Enabled="false">
        <Policy Class="com.tridion.cache.LRUPolicy" Type="LRU">
            <Param Name="MemSize" Value="16mb"/>
        </Policy>
        <Features>
            <Feature Class="com.tridion.cache.DependencyTracker" Type="DependencyTracker"/>
        </Features>
    </ObjectCache>
    <Storages>
        <StorageBindings>
            <Bundle src="SearchDAOBundle.xml"/>
        </StorageBindings>
        <Storage Class="com.tridion.storage.si4t.JPASearchDAOFactory" Id="defaultdb" Type="persistence" dialect="MSSQL">
            <Pool CheckoutTimeout="120" IdleTimeout="120" MonitorInterval="60" Size="5" Type="jdbc"/>
            <DataSource Class="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource">
                <Property Name="serverName" Value="DEVAG02\SQL01"/>
                <Property Name="portNumber" Value="9561"/>
                <Property Name="databaseName" Value="Tridion_Broker"/>
                <Property Name="user" Value="Tridion"/>
                <Property Name="password" Value="Tridion"/>
            </DataSource>
            <Indexer Class="org.si4t.cloudsearch.CloudSearchIndexer" DocExtensions="txt" access_key_id="KEW6HC74334" authentication="explicit" documentEndpoint="doc-dev-live-le-5yist4ubp3pr2gq3pbwevm22uq.eu-west-1.cloudsearch.amazonaws.com" indexBatchSize="20" secret_access_key="QT5LDTKcg2tyVq9TP70k7fOqM9/pS"/>
        </Storage>
        <Storage Class="com.tridion.storage.si4t.FSSearchDAOFactory" Id="defaultFile" Type="filesystem" defaultFilesystem="false">
            <Root Path="D:\DevLivePublic\live"/>
            <Indexer Class="org.si4t.cloudsearch.CloudSearchIndexer" DocExtensions="txt" access_key_id="KEW6HC74334" authentication="explicit" documentEndpoint="doc-dev-live-le-5yist4ubp3pr2gq3pbwevm22uq.eu-west-1.cloudsearch.amazonaws.com" indexBatchSize="20" secret_access_key="QT5LDTKcg2tyVq9TP70k7fOqM9/pS"/>
        </Storage>
        <Storage Class="com.tridion.storage.filesystem.FSDAOFactory" Id="cie_index_files" Type="filesystem" defaultFilesystem="false" defaultStorage="false">
            <Root Path="D:\DevLivePublic\live\CIE\SearchIndex\Resources"/>
        </Storage>
        <Storage Class="com.tridion.storage.filesystem.FSDAOFactory" Id="ocr_index_files" Type="filesystem" defaultFilesystem="false" defaultStorage="false">
            <Root Path="D:\DevLivePublic\live\OC\SearchIndex\Resources"/>
        </Storage>
        <Storage Class="com.tridion.storage.si4t.FSSearchDAOFactory" Id="ce_index_files" Type="filesystem" defaultFilesystem="false" defaultStorage="false">
            <Root Path="D:\DevLivePublic\live\ESOL\SearchIndex\Resources"/>
            <Indexer Class="org.si4t.cloudsearch.CloudSearchIndexer" DocExtensions="txt" access_key_id="AKIKEW6HC74" authentication="explicit" documentEndpoint="doc-dev-live-le-5yist4ubp3pr2gwevm22uq.eu-west-1.cloudsearch.amazonaws.com" indexBatchSize="20" secret_access_key="QT54AZNTLDTKcg2tyVq9TP70k7fOqM9/pS"/>
        </Storage>
    </Storages>
    <Transaction MonitorInterval="5000" Timeout="10000000"/>
</Global>
<ItemTypes cached="false" defaultStorageId="defaultdb">
    <Item cached="true" storageId="defaultFile" typeMapping="Page"/>
    <Item cached="true" storageId="defaultFile" typeMapping="Binary"/>
    <Publication Id="31" cached="true" defaultStorageId="defaultdb">
        <Item cached="true" storageId="defaultFile" typeMapping="Page"/>
        <Item cached="true" storageId="defaultFile" typeMapping="Binary"/>
        <Item cached="false" itemExtension=".xml" storageId="cie_index_files" typeMapping="ComponentPresentation"/>
    </Publication>
    <Publication Id="33" cached="true" defaultStorageId="defaultdb">
        <Item cached="true" storageId="defaultFile" typeMapping="Page"/>
        <Item cached="true" storageId="defaultFile" typeMapping="Binary"/>
        <Item cached="false" itemExtension=".xml" storageId="ocr_index_files" typeMapping="ComponentPresentation"/>
    </Publication>
    <Publication Id="32" cached="true" defaultStorageId="defaultdb">
        <Item cached="true" storageId="defaultFile" typeMapping="Page"/>
        <Item cached="true" storageId="defaultFile" typeMapping="Binary"/>
        <Item cached="false" itemExtension=".htm" storageId="defaultdb" typeMapping="Page"/>
        <Item cached="false" itemExtension=".xml" storageId="ce_index_files" typeMapping="ComponentPresentation"/>
    </Publication>
    <Publication Id="141" cached="true" defaultStorageId="defaultdb"/>
    <Publication Id="142" cached="true" defaultStorageId="defaultdb"/>
    <Publication Id="123" cached="true" defaultStorageId="defaultdb"/>
</ItemTypes>
<ConfigRepository CacheEnabled="true" CacheExpirationDuration="600" ClientId="registration" ClientSecret="encrypted:HzfQh9wYwAKShDxCm4DnnBnysAz9PtbDMFXMbPszSVY=" ConnectionTimeout="20000" ServiceMonitorPollDuration="10" ServiceUri="http://cdlive-dev:9082/discovery.svc" TokenServiceUrl="http://cdlive-dev:9082/token.svc">
    <Roles>
        <Role Name="DeployerCapability" Url="http://cdlive-dev:9084/httpupload">
            <Property Name="encoding" Value="UTF-8"/>
        </Role>
    </Roles>
</ConfigRepository>
```

I hope it helps

Comment: after updating now i am getting the following error. java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.tridion.storage.si4t.JPADAOFactory, I have updated latest log in main question.

Comment: Ah, sorry not JPADAOFactory it's com.tridion.storage.si4t.JPASearchDAOFactory and same it's not FSDAOFactory, It's com.tridion.storage.si4t.FSSearchDAOFactory, updated the answer with corrected config,

Comment: Even after updating new class name I am getting same error with new class name

Comment: When I going through documentation, one thing i noticed is FS configuration in cloud search,once i removed FS configuration issue resolved, But not sure why my old team configured component presentation for same publication. Can we configure FS in cloud Search or not?

Comment: Good to know it works, It depends if those DCP items also required to index then yes should be configured FS for cloud search if then not required.